# Unable to load Nativescript IOS App Resources Images

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have the following App_Resources Folder:

[image]

Here is how I used the image:

```
<Image src="res://asianconnectlogo" width="75%" class="logo"></Image>
```

However the image is not loading at all. Why is that so?

I tried tns prepare ios but still not working and the resources are not copied into platforms folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Try a clean build - delete the platforms folder and do tns run again. Not sure which layout you are using to place the image, try setting height too to make sure the image has enough space to display the image.

Comment: Will try a clean build... This is working on android :)

Comment: @Manoj hi thanks its working!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes on `App_Resources` will usually be detected and CLI will perform a rebuild automatically. But it may fail sometimes in which case you shall perform a clean build manually by running `tns platform clean <Platform>` Or alternatively by simply deleting the platforms folder.

Also, I'm not sure which layout you are using to place the Image, try setting a height too to make sure the image has enough space to display the image.